# how to proper redirect permanently in lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, 301-redirect

The following config (`/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`) seems to redirect to the default page

```
$HTTP["host"] == "pool.ntp.org|ch.pool.ntp.org" {
    accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/pool.ntp.org_access.log"
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/$" {
        url.redirect = ( "" => "https://ntppool.org" )
        url.redirect-code = 302
    }
}
```

what would be the proper way to redirect this traffic?

With this entered and a hosts file having pointing pool.ntp.org to the ip of this server the result is a page containt `<h1>default</h1>` which is the content of the default servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-posted.  (Please do not do that or at least link them to cross-reference!)

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/11458

`$HTTP["host"] == "pool.ntp.org|ch.pool.ntp.org" {`

should instead be

`$HTTP["host"] =~ "pool.ntp.org|ch.pool.ntp.org" {`

since it looks like you intended a regex.

For exact match of host, I would use a more precise regex

`$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(?:ch\.)?pool\.ntp\.org$" {`

You might have troubleshot this yourself using
[Configuration: Debug Variables](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/DebugVariables)

`debug.log-condition-handling = "enable"`

Also relevant: [HowToRedirectHttpToHttps](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/HowToRedirectHttpToHttps)

Comment: thanks! I'm not sure how redmine.lighttpd.net and serverfault are related but if you say it is a multipost you probably are right. The internet is a fast place. I did not intend a regexp but it looks like you pointed in the right way. thanks

Comment: Did you make "multi"ple "posts" with the same text in different places?  That is a "multi" "post".